# Error when plotting object of class tune in Jupyter Notebook but works in RStudio - how to fix it?

Tags: r, plot, jupyter-notebook, nnet

I tuned an nnet as follows :

```
tune1 <- tune.nnet(O3obs~., # formule
                   data=datappr, # choix des données
                   size=c(2,3,4), # choix entre les 3 sizes précisés
                   decay=c(1,2,3), # choix entre les 3 decays précisés
                   maxit=200,
                   linout=TRUE) # Sortie continue - pb de regression
```

Then when I try to plot tune1 in Jupyter Notebook, I have the following error :

```
Error in plot.new(): outer margins too large (figure region too small)
Traceback:

1. plot(tune1)
2. plot(tune1)
3. plot.tune(tune1)
4. filled.contour(x = as.double(rownames(x)), y = as.double(colnames(x)), 
 .     xlab = xlab, ylab = ylab, nlevels = nlevels, color.palette = color.palette, 
 .     main = main, x, ...)
5. plot.new()
```

It is working in Rstudio though.

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the plot bigger.  In most R frontends, you'd specify `width` and `height` when you open the graphics device.  According to this old post https://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2015/09/resizing-plots-in-the-r-kernel-for-jupyter-notebooks.html you do that in Jupyter using code like

```
options(repr.plot.width=4, repr.plot.height=3)
```

If you still get the error, try larger numbers.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have already tried larger numbers (really larger !!) but still not working.

Comment: You should edit your question to show an example of what you tried.